# azure: az resource list missing tags

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

It tells me I have `null` tags if I list my resources with `az resource list --tag Departement=Finance`

```
az resource list --tag Departement=Finance
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/28b7bf82-0a7d-4ca7-9827-811c620d6d52/resourceGroups/msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/msftlearn-vnet1",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": null,
    "location": "switzerlandnorth",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "msftlearn-vnet1",
    "plan": null,
    "properties": null,
    "resourceGroup": "msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg",
    "sku": null,
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
  }
]
```

But with `az resource list --resource-group msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg` it shows me all the tags.

```
az resource list --resource-group msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/28b7bf82-0a7d-4ca7-9827-811c620d6d52/resourceGroups/msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/msftlearn-vnet1",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": null,
    "location": "switzerlandnorth",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "msftlearn-vnet1",
    "plan": null,
    "properties": null,
    "resourceGroup": "msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg",
    "sku": null,
    "tags": {
      "Departement": "Finance",
      "Environment": "learn"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
  },
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/28b7bf82-0a7d-4ca7-9827-811c620d6d52/resourceGroups/msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/msftlearn-vnet2",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": null,
    "location": "switzerlandnorth",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "msftlearn-vnet2",
    "plan": null,
    "properties": null,
    "resourceGroup": "msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg",
    "sku": null,
    "tags": {
      "Departement": "Marketing",
      "Environment": "learn"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
  }
]
```

Is this a bug or does it have to be like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug.

The command `az resource list --tag Departement=Finance` essentially calls this REST API [`Resources - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) with the `$filter`, you could use `--debug` in the command to check.

```
az resource list --tag Departement=Finance --debug
```

[image]

The response will not include the `tags` property, so the `tags` will be null of the command result. You can also click the `Try it` button in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list), login to test with `$filter` directly.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resources?api-version=2019-10-01&%24filter=tagName%20eq%20%27Departement%27%20and%20tagValue%20eq%20%27Finance%27
```

[image]

[image]

---

When running `az resource list --resource-group msftlearn-core-infrastructure-rg`, it calls [`Resources - List By Resource Group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/listbyresourcegroup), the `tags` will be included in the result.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Joy thanks a lot for your detailed and understandable answer.